# Laravel - How to display in blade videos saved in storage?

Tags: laravel, path, storage

I need to display in blade the videos uploaded in storage/videos and i don't know how to do.
For uploading them in storage i put this code in filesystems.php

```html
        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        'video' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path(),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'storage/video',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

I tried many combinations for the path but anyone doesnt's work

```html
url/storage/video/VHqPwguZeM6mf4csBTfj.mp4 

or 

url/storage/VHqPwguZeM6mf4csBTfj.mp4

or 

url/video/VHqPwguZeM6mf4csBTfj.mp4
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Go to the `Network` tab in your browser's developer tools and try to see the URL its trying to access to get the video.

Comment: Only files in the `storage/app/public` directory are publicly accessible as you can read [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#the-public-disk). If you want to return files outside of the `public` directory to the user you would have to create a custom route with a file response, you can read more about it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/responses#file-responses).

Answer (score -1):

The solution is easy once you have uploaded the video in storage/videos you have to do two steps:

1. php artisan storage:link
   this command links your public folder with storage after that you can find a shortcut of storage folder in your public folder.
   2.In your blade file just do this:

Comment: The `php artisan storage:link` command only creates a symlink between `public/storage` and `storage/app/public`, the files are however stored in `storage/video`. How is this supposed to work?

Comment: in your database you must store the name of the video, after that it will be stored in storage i know but through php artisan storage:link storage file will be in public as a shortcut. CONSIDER STORAGE AS A FOLDER IN PUBLIC AFTER THIS COMMAND